# Помощь по Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cms

Всем привет. У меня есть задание надо написать CMS Rails Admin чтобы изменять данные в Landing Page. Не знаю Ruby on Rails( Помогите, дайте видео уроки. Посмотрел это видео [Как написать блог за 15 минут на Ruby on Rails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecxezoc0uv0). но этого не хватает мне. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Active admin предоставляет все необходимые функции админки.

Репозиторий: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin

Сайт: http://activeadmin.info/

---

Так же придется создать пару моделей для ваших Landing Page.

Урок по основам моделей в Rails: http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails#sozdanie-modeli-article

Comment: а есть документация для Ubuntu? и можете сказать с чего надо начинать?

Comment: Для Ubuntu вот: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04
А дальше разработка одинакова, вне зависимости от ОС
http://rusrails.ru/ -- На этом сайте, собственно, есть ответы на все интересующие вас типичные вопросы. Будут конкретные проблемы -- добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow :)

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: Благодарить в комментариях на SO не принято. Вместо этого лучше примите мой ответ, как верный. Ну и плюсануть никогда не грех :P